# Disabling one of the navigation view bar without having to remove the manual push segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a login view implementation and a slide out sidebar menu that is connected to parse as backend. Individually both are working just fine. But when I connect all of them all together to my profile view, I get a result like this[my profile view image here](http://puu.sh/4qZRn). As you can see I have an extra navigation bar menu that comes from my login view implementation. This is how my storyboard looks like [storyboard here](http://puu.sh/4qZHI). And this is the slider I am using.[link to slider](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController).

**What I would like to achieve**

I believe the most efficient way would be disabling the navigation bar that comes from login/signup view controller once the user reaches the my menu and keep the navigation that comes from the slider. Once the user decides to sign out, re- enabling the navigation so that  the user can sign in again. Is it possible to do this? If so, would it be ideal?

**The other way**

The only other way I can think of is using the manual segue again but instead of pushing, I have to segue modally from signIn/login to the controller where the slider begins.

```
- (void)checkStatus {
    NSLog(@"Splash - checkStatus");
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [loginButton setHidden:YES];
    [signupButton setHidden:YES];

    if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"splashToMain" sender:self];
    } else {
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        [loginButton setHidden:NO];
        [signupButton setHidden:NO];
    }    
}
```

If anyone can help me with this problem, I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do it is to use the `UINavigationController` navigation for the actual app and present the Login/Sign Up view controllers as modal view controllers, if the user is not logged in when the app launches. You can present a `UINavigationController` as modal on top of your main one, so you can have separate navigation for the Login part.

Comment: this is ridiculous! It seems like I was way over thinking this. Since my segues were already implemented manually, all I did was changing the style to Modal from storyboard. Thank you.